# Regular Expressions ~ convert UNC to URL

Tags: c#, regex, uri, unc

I'm looking for a nice tight regex solution to this problem.  I'm looking to reformat an UNC into a Uri

Problem:

UNC directory needs to be reformatted into a Uri

**\\server\d$\x\y\z\AAA**

needs to look like:

**http://server/z/AAA**

Comment: How do you know that "d$\x\y\" should be removed from the middle?

Comment: The web server is mapped to z, so those other guys in the middle don't need to be seen in the final url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a replace is easier to write and understand than Regex in this case.  Given:

```
string input = "\\\\server\\d$\\x\\y\\z\\AAA";
```

You can do a double replace:

```
string output = String.Format("http:{0}", input.Replace("\\d$\\x\\y", String.Empty).Replace("\\", "/"));
```

Answer (score 5):

.Net framework supports a class called [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) which can do the conversion. It is simpler and handles the escape cases. It handles both UNC, local paths to Uri format.

C#:

```
Console.WriteLine((new System.Uri("C:\Temp\Test.xml")).AbsoluteUri);
```

PowerShell:

```
(New-Object System.Uri 'C:\Temp\Test.xml').AbsoluteUri
```

Output:

```
file:///C:/Temp/Test.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\\\\\w+)\\.*(\\\w\\\w+)$
```

- First match: `\\server`
- Second match: `\z\AAA`

Concatenate to a string and then prepend `http:` to get `http:\\server\z\AAA`. Replace `\` with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Two operations:

- first, replace `"(.*)d\$\\x\\y\\(.*)"` with `"http:\1\2"` - that'll clear out the `d$\x\y\`, and prepend the `http:`.
- Then replace `\\` with `/`  to finish the job.

Job done!

Edit: I'm assuming that in C#, "`\1`" contains the first parenthesised match (it does in Perl). If it doesn't, then it should be clear what is meant above :)