# string replace vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net, string

What am I doing wrong here?

```
If FilePath.ToLower().Contains(".pdf") Then
    Dim Replaced As String = FilePath.Replace("\","/")
    FilePath = "http:" & Replaced
End If
```

If FilePath is for example `\\sharepoint\file.pdf`, the expected output should be `http://sharepoint/file.pdf`. However, the actual output is `http:\\sharepoint\file.pdf`

**Update 1**

This is the original string:
[image: original string]

This is what it looks like after my VB code:
[image: replaced string]

As you can see, the http: part is added, however the backslashes haven't been touched.

**Update 2**
It has something to do with the slashes. Because when I replace other characters (for example a with @), then the replaced string is shown correctly. But not the slashes

Comment: Are you *sure* FilePath contains: `\\sharepoint\file.pdf` at the start?  How are you testing the input / output values?

Comment: I tried your code and unable to replicate. Please check: http://imgur.com/09Iwq Did you define FilePath as described?

Comment: Related to [Regular Expressions ~ convert UNC to URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053300/regular-expressions-convert-unc-to-url)

Comment: @forsvarir, @Alex, see updated question. I added pictures so you can see that it does change *something*

Comment: @stefan, the code in the accepted answer does not work in my case (even when converted to VB.net)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how your pictures are related to your code.  If you put a breakpoint in your code, where you're doing the conversion, what's contained in `FilePath`.  It may be that some escaping is necessary, "\\", or @"\"...

Comment: I thought it's _VB.net_. In your edit it appears to be _vbscript_. Checking...

Comment: @Alex R.: I assumed the function supplied was being used to help produce the VB script...

Comment: @jao Both this code and the code in the related question **definitely** work. Your error is somewhere else, and completely unrelated. I’m assuming that you are throwing away the result value somewhere in between.

Comment: @forsvarir: Ok my bad, didn't read the code thoroughly. So it's still vb.net. But still unreproducible as my previous post.

Comment: Strange, it works for me:         
        Dim FilePath = "\\Test.pdf"
        FilePath = Replace(FilePath, "\", "/")
        MsgBox(FilePath)
Please check your text. Are you sure it is "\", or some character that have the visual like "\" character?

Comment: it is vb.net that gets executed inside a vbscript

Comment: @Konrad I think that is what went wrong, however I can only access part of the code as the rest of it is compiled in a DLL. See my answer below. It must've been something with throwing away the result (however, that does not explain why the http: still was added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't exactly understand why, but the following has fixed my code:

```
Dim Replaced As String = FilePath
If FilePath.ToLower().Contains(".pdf") Then
    Replaced = FilePath.Replace("\","/")
    Replaced = "http:" & Replaced
End If
```

and then in the vbscript code I use

```
Sub toonDocument()
dim spobject
set spobject = CreateObject("Sharepoint.Document")
spobject.FilePath = "<% = Replaced %>"
spobject.openen()
set spobject = nothing
```

so `<% = Replaced %>` (instead of `<%= FilePath %>`)